# How to check if a property exists in an object's prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in Javascript and trying to learn this language. After going through several posts I figured out that in order to check an Object's particular property we can broadly use one of the following methods.

1] Using hasOwnProperty

Object.hasOwnProperty("propertyName")

However this does not check properties inherited from the Object's prototype chain.

2] Loop over all the properties and check if property exists.

```
for(propertyName in myObject) {
    // Check if "propertyName" is the particular property you want.
}
```

Using this you can check Object's properties in the prototype chain too.

My question is: Is there a method other than 2] by which I can check if "propertyName" is a property in Object's prototype chain? Something similar to "hasOwnProperty" and without looping?

Comment: Uhm `if ('propertyName' in myObject)`, you don't have to iterate ?

Comment: Why not `if ('propertyName' in obj.prototype)` ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just check the property directly with [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), and it will check the prototype chain as well, like this

```
if ('propertyName' in myObject)
```

an example

```
var obj = function() {};

obj.prototype.test = function() {};

var new_obj = new obj();

console.log( 'test' in new_obj ); // true
console.log( 'test22222' in new_obj ); // false
console.log( new_obj.hasOwnProperty('test') ); // false
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5j3Ks/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Reflect.has can make a work for you

```
console.log(Reflect.has({}, 'toString')); // true
```